# Learning ASP.NET MVC 3 EntityFramework library 4.1.0.0 (not the latest) and getting no data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My context is:

```
public class RegistrationManagerContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()                
            .ToTable("aspnet_Users");
    }
}
```

and my User class is:

```
[Table("aspnet_Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = true)]
    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [DataType("nvarchar")]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public AccountProfile Profile
    { 
        get 
        { 
            if (_profile == null)
            {
                _profile = AccountProfile.GetUserProfile(this.UserName);
            }
            return _profile;
        }
    }
    private AccountProfile _profile = null;
}
```

and my call method (Controller) is:

```
namespace RegistrationManager.Controllers
{

    [Authorize(Roles="Admins")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {

        private RegistrationManagerContext db = new RegistrationManagerContext();

        //
        // GET: /Admin/

        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var viewModel = db.Users;
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                ViewBag.UserID = id.Value;
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }

    }
}
```

My view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<RegistrationManager.Models.User>

@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

<h2>Users</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Given Names</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Last Ac</th>
        <th>Refresh</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string selectedRow = "";
    if (ViewBag.UserId != null && item.UserId == ViewBag.UserId)  
    {  
        selectedRow = "selectedrow";  
    }  
    <tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top">
        <td>
            @item.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Profile.GivenNames
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Profile.Surname
        </td>
        <td>
            @String.Format("{0:d}", item.LastActivityDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Refresh", "Refresh", "Admin", new { id = item.UserId }) 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

So what am I doing wrong or what am I missing?? As I get no data!!?? There is definitely data as I should at least see my own login, right!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var viewModel = db.Users.Where(x=>x.UserId == id.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            //ViewBag.UserID = id.Value; //You do not need it here
            if(viewModel != null)
                  return View(viewModel);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("UsersListPage");
    }
```

UPDATE #1

Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Index(){
           return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.User>

    @foreach (var user in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)
        </td>            
    </tr>
     }
```

Isn't this working for you?

Comment: The Guid part yes my mistake but not that revelant to the question being asked, the id is just there to show the Selected index on post back so for now just ignore the if (id.HasValue) statement. I.e. I want to show all Users in my View.

Comment: Updated answer, feel free to add more information if this is not what you are looking forward.

Comment: My view is pretty much as you have listed it. NB: I have added it to my original question above. NO DATA from aspnet_Users is coming throw to my db.Users object. The sql is: SELECT 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Extent1].[LastActivityDate] AS [LastActivityDate]
FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [Extent1]

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the controller and tell me the "length" of that list, if it's 0, then really check the connection string because you maybe are accessing other DB and not the one you think. If there is an "exception" that please write it here for us to see.

Comment: Yes the length is 0. No exceptions. View is only showing header row and no data. Not sure what you mean about connection string as I run the query in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and it works fine. Connection is windows authentication to a local SQLExpress database. Same connection in the Web.Config file as I connect to in MS-SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You wrote in the class: table = aspnet_Users, sure, but in which Database? You may have an instance of the SQLExpress but there you may have several Databases and perhaps you are making the query on the wrong one. The problem here needs to be on the DB, becase, if you are getting a list of 0 and without exception this means that the query is being executed successfully. Now, how sure are you that the table has something? Please check if you are "hitting" the correct DB and correct table.

Comment: I have only one database with the schema and it is a .\SQLExpress isntance database. There is no other connectionstring in my Web.Config file. I deleted the default connectionstring "ApplicationServices" so it definately my database. I ran the tool myself to add the schema to my local database. In VS the db object's connectionstring is as I expect: "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RegistrationManager.DAL.RegistrationManagerContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True". The only thing of note is the Initial Catalog has changed from my database name to Context class.

Comment: At this point there is nothing else to point out, if you get some entries by querying directly the DB in SQL Management studio and in the MVC EF Website you get 0 entries, then for me the meaning can ONLY be: you have 2 DBs (catalogs) with the tables with the same name and different BD entries. That is the only explanation.

Comment: Okay I believe you are correct on that account. But why??!!?? How is this possible, I am NOT doing code first development. I just refreshed by Management studio and a brand new database has been created called RegistrationManager.DAL.RegisrationManagerContext with a single table only with no data called ... wait for it ... aspnet_Users. Again how and why did this database get created. I assume I will just delete this database and see where I end up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21058/discussion-between-dryadwoods-and-glen)

Comment: Ok I have figured it out and I have to give it to you even though it was me who is the complete ignoramous. My ConectionStringName has to include the suffix "...Context" because my name space is the same name.

Comment: :) nice to know that you were able to solve your problem :) thanks for the vote.